# Reference Request: Abstract Exposition of Galois Theory

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory

I have a reference request concerning Galois theory. I have a concrete knowledge of Galois theory (I have read the relevant chapters in Dummit and Foote, for those of you familiar with this). I am looking for a textbook on a more abstract and theoretical level. For instance, an abstract approach might avoid choosing bases where it can. Hopefully this would give more insight into some of the fundamental theorems in the subject. So,

1) What are some good expositions of Galois theory on a more abstract level?

2) What would be a good source to read after reading Dummit and Foote chapters 13 and 14 (for those of you who know what this is)?